# Swift compiler crashes: Illegal instruction: 4, non-canonical or unchecked type

Tags: swift, enums, swift2

The Swift compiler (Xcode 7.0 beta 5) crashes with "Illegal instruction: 4", "non-canonical or unchecked type" when fed this specific source line (inside a larger piece of code):

```
let z = y.filter() { (_, x) in x.type == .A(_) }
```

The elements of `y` are tuples. Their first elements extend `NSObject`. Their second elements have a property `type`, which is an enumeration that includes `A(Int)`.

Is there an (obvious) mistake in my code?

**UPDATE** If I attempt this work-around I run into errors "Use of unresolved identifier 'x'" in the lines that contain `if` and `append` respectively:

```
var z = []
for (_, x: X) in y {
    if x.type == .A(_) {
        z.append((_, x))
    }
}
```

Again, is there an (obvious) mistake in this code?

Comment: Please, file [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com). Even invalid code (not saying yours is invalid) must not crash compiler.

Comment: @robertvojta I will, but (judging from past experience) this won't lead to a quick solution.

Comment: if there's Swift / crash in report title, their reaction time is much more shorter than it used to be. It's worth to fill it otherwise it can still be there in future updates.

Comment: @robertvojta Submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let z = y.filter() { (_, x) in x.type == .A(_) }
```

If your array is array of tuples, as you wrote, closure signature is ...

```
(t) -> Bool
```

... where `t` is your tuple and `Bool` is return value. If `true` is returned, `t` is included in result otherwise it's not. You have to access elements of your tuple with `t.0` and `t.1`.

```
for (_, x: X) in y {
    if x.type == .A(_) {
        z.append((_, x))
    }
}
```

It's not possible to check `.type` with `== .A` like you do. Also you're saying that you're not interested in first elements of your tuples (`_` in `for ... in` loop) and later you're trying to use first element with `_`, which is not going to work as well.

---

Let's define some types first ...

```
enum MyType {
  case A(Int)
  case B(Float)
}

class Dummy: NSObject {}

class DummyValue {
  var type: MyType

  init(_ type: MyType) {
    self.type = type
  }
}
```

... and now some `DummyValue` ...

```
let dv = DummyValue(.A(1))
```

You're trying to check `type` with ...

```
if dv.type == .A(_) { ... }
```

... which is not going to work. You can use `switch` ...

```
switch dv.type {
  case .A(_): print(".A")
  default: print("Other")
}
```

... or pattern matching with `if` & `case` ...

```
if case .A(_) = dv.type {
  print(".A")
}
```

Let's transform your `for in` loop to a working form ...

```
let y = [
  (Dummy(), DummyValue(.A(1))),
  (Dummy(), DummyValue(.B(3.0))),
  (Dummy(), DummyValue(.A(2)))
]

var z = [(Dummy,DummyValue)]()
for (a, b) in y {
  if case .A(_) = b.type {
    z.append((a,b))
  }
}

print(z.count) // Output = 2
```

It's not nice and we don't want to have `if case ...` or `switch ...` in our `filter` ...

```
z = y.filter { if case .A(_) = $0.1.type { return true }; return false }
```

... so, we can extend `MyType` with computed property `isA` ...

```
extension MyType {
  var isA: Bool {
    switch self {
      case .A(_): return true
      default: return false
    }
  }
}
```

... and transform `filter` into this simple form ...

```
z = y.filter { $0.1.type.isA }
```

I can dream of nicer solution, but since there're still some limitations in pattern matching in current beta ... :-)